# can not see anything in xib

Tags: ios, xib

What happened to my xib, I can not see anything in my xib; this project was checkout from svn; and the version of Xcode is Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UI Elements has been added to different Size Class, change the size class to desired size class and you'll able to see the Elements again.
[image]

---

[image]